# phpseclib return no result even on simple command

Tags: php, linux, ssh, phpseclib

I want to add ssh user via php. So I try phpseclib. Unfortunately, the script does not return any result neither any user created. Then I tried to make a simple command `ls -la`. Still no result, just loading for a few secs and return a blank page.

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');  
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'); 
if (!$ssh->login('root', 'abc123')) { 
 exit('Login Failed'); 
 echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
}
```

Im using PHP 5.3.3 with Centos 6.5

P/S:
 I checked apache log and /var/log/messages.. There is no error.

Comment: The `exec` line can never be executed (any missing codes?)

Comment: what I am missing here? Sorry but I dont know what

Comment: oh.. } at the end? it is just a typo..corrected :)

Comment: No. The `exit()` already terminate the execution of codes

Comment: For years im working with PHP, this is the first time I did this silly mistakes T_T ..Sorry for making this silly mistakes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: :) accept the answer if you find it useful, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exit()` command will terminate the consequent codes after it. You may probably want:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');  
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'); 
if (!$ssh->login('root', 'abc123')) { 
 exit('Login Failed'); 
}
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
```